# Phonegap Build ios 6 iphone 5 splash not going away

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Hey all i have created an android/iphone app that works just fine on android but for some reason it just showing the splash screen/loading animation and not going past that.

Here is what the screen looks like:

[image]

in my config.xml file i have:

```
<!--App settings -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"                                     value="2.3.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"                                          value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"                                           value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"                                      value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"                              value="false" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration"                               value="10000" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce"                                        value="true" />
```

And in my javascript i have:

```
    //Wait for device
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

However, i am using this code for the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=310;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    window.location='https://fb.zzzzzzz.com/xxxxxx/index.php';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What settings am i missing? Could it be because i am calling a .php page after the .html?

Comment: Have you tried removing that script which calls .php file?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after the device ready event was fired and handled.

JavaScript

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        window.location='https://fb.zzzzzzz.com/xxxxxx/index.php';
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
```